# List repositories from private docker registry

Tags: docker

I need to be able to list/delete image and repositories to my private registry. I tried with:

```
docker search registry.mydomain.com
```

with this result:

```
NAME      DESCRIPTION   STARS     OFFICIAL   AUTOMATED
```

I have pushed two images to two different repositories:

```
registry.mydomain.com/repo1/mysql:v2
registry.mydomain.com/repo2/apache:demo
```

In the registry under `repositories` directory, I see the `repo1` and `repo2` directories, but `docker search` doenn't list anything.

Answer (score 2):

Docker search registry v2 functionality is currently not supported at the time of this writing. See discussion since Feb 2015: "propose registry search functionality #206" https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/206

I wrote a script that you can find: https://github.com/BradleyA/Search-docker-registry-v2-script.1.0 It is not pretty but it gets the information needed from the private registry.

Comment: Have you considered making a PR related to the docker ticket?